# How to create a group action table with Mathematica?

Tags: group-theory

Background: I want to explain the [Sylow Theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) as detailed as possible, therefore I am rewriting the proof using concrete examples.

Since the answers to my questions ( about Mathematica ) have often, if not always, exceeded my expectations, and I lack the tools to adequately show a table, I start with a compact description of my question. I can elaborate if required, of course.

Question:

**Is it possible to create a group action table with Mathematica?**

For example:

Let $G = \left\{ 1,a,a^2, b, ba, ba^2 \right \}$, where $a^3=b^2=1, ab=ba^2 (D3) $ .

Let $S$ be the set of subsets of size $3$ of $G$: $\left\{ \left\{ 1,a,a^2 \right \}, \left\{1,a,b \right \}, ..., \left\{b,ba,ba^2 \right \} \right \} $ .

Define the map $f: G \times S \rightarrow S \ $ by $(g,s) \mapsto gs$.

**The group action table, illustrating the map $f$ would be of size 20 X 6 with each cell containing an element of $S$.**

I have ( experience with ) the Mathematica AbstractAlgebra package. I'll accept answers in GAP also.

Comment: Tables work fine in MathJax, but you need to end a line with \\ (double backslash), as I showed you in the [answer to your meta question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-question)  I have removed the MathJax experimentation from your post, as it was not connected to the question.  Can you post the table you meant to post?

Comment: @ziyuang - Permuting what ?

Comment: @Szabolcs - I am doing two group action tables in Excel and learning about group actions in GAP. Will post image when done. Probably tomorrow.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Click. I got it about the LaTeX tables now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MMA v.8 provides support for (finite) Group Theory, however this answer will not make use of that functionality.

We shall use the `**` (`NonCommutativeMultiply`) command present in MMA, which allows us to create [*semigroups*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) quite easily.

In a fresh MMA session:

`Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];`

`GroupAction[g_, s_] := (g ** #) & /@ s`

1 is the identity:

`g_ ** 1 := g`

`1 ** g_ := g`

Elements relations

`a ** a ** a := 1`

`b ** b := 1`

`b ** a ** a := a ** b`

Then

```
G = {1, a, a ** a, b, b ** a, b ** a ** a}

S = Subsets[G, {3}]
```

Check some products:

`a ** 1 ** b ** q`

`a ** 1 ** b ** b ** q`

`a ** 1 ** b ** a ** a ** b ** q`

`p ** a ** a ** a ** q`

(p and q are generic group elemants) as you see MMA uses the associative (Flat) property of NonCommutativeMultiply to parse and simplify the expressions in all possible ways.
Now this is your table:

`Table[GroupAction[g, s], {s, S}, {g, G}] // MatrixForm`

Nicely formatted:

`Grid[Prepend[Table[GroupAction[g, s], {s, S}, {g, G}], G], 
 Background -> {None, {Lighter[Blue, .9], {White, 
     Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}]`

If you are serious about Group Theory, you might want to check the functionalities offered by MMA v.8

Comment: I can make another answer - tomorrow -  using the Group theory functions in MMA v.8 if you are interested.

Comment: Do you know why is a seemingly inert (and unused by the system) symbol like `NonCommutativeMultiply` protected?

Comment: One might sometimes prefer `Outer[]` to `Table[]` for generating the Cayley table of a binary operation...

Comment: I know that GAP is the tool for Group Theory, but GAP has quite a learning curve. Although not a cross-poster I asked in the Mathematica section. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103220/how-do-i-create-a-group-action-table-with-gap This basically works for any group and subset size. - I have invested a lot in learning Mathematica but it can handle very limited functionality in Group Theory. Developing a parser to and from GAP from Mathematica is on my list. They did it for SAGE, it can be done.

Comment: Will test the answer later. NonCommutativeMultiply is new for me. Thanks.

Comment: If using the notation G = {1, a, a ** a, b, b ** a, b ** a ** a}; for the group elements I assume you meant a ** b := b ** a ** a instead of b ** a ** a := a ** b ? In the latter case, it works.

Comment: I do not understand -completely- your comment. Anyway: I copied G from your question. MMA will immediately transform it into G = {1, a, a ** a, b, b ** a,a ** b} (using my code), so you may as well start from this directly. The alternative rule a ** b := b ** a ** a is not good since you would replace a short string (a**b) with a longer one.

Answer (score 4):

Not very elegant and it requires additional work on the rules :

```
elem = {1, a, b}
rules = {a^3 -> 1, a^4 -> a, b^2 -> 1, b^3 -> b, b a^2 -> a b, b^4 -> 1}
bigG = Union[Times @@ # & /@ Tuples[elem, {2}]]
bigS = Subsets[bigG, {3}]
TableView[ 
   Outer[Sort[#1 #2 //. rules] &, bigG, bigS, 1, 1], 
   TableHeadings -> {bigG, bigS} 
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This does not work correctly, since the multiplication in D3 is not commutative, while `Times` is commutative. You would get wrong results using this table.

Comment: @magma Thanks for the clarification. I am not familiar with this group and it was not specified in the question that the multiplication is non-commutative.

Comment: Instead of the undocumented (and here practically unnecessary) `TableView`, you can consider `MatrixForm[ ... , TableDepth -> 2]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks $ab=ba^3$ means non-commutative.

Comment: @ndroock1 Thanks for the clarification.